How to replicate the production schema in a testcontainer using jooq?
Is it possible to initialize a database in a testcontainer using jooq programmatically at runtime rather than build time, or do I have to execute the DDL files?

Yes it's possible

You can use create.execute(ddl(TABLE).getSQL()) for simple cases, but if your table contains foreign keys, it is better to execute the DDL files by replacing execute's argument with a string containing the contents of the DDL files.
